# How to get module state props as single computed props (not as props of an object) from Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a state with single module:

```js
   const charactersModule = {
      state: () => ({
        characters: [],
        isLoading: false,
        totalPages: 0,
        currentPage: 1,
        itemsPerPage: ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
      }),
      getters: {},
      mutations: {},
      actions: {
        async getCharacters({state}, page = state.currentPage) {
          try {
            state.isLoading = true;
            const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}character/?page=${page}`);
    
            if (res.ok) {
              const { info, results } = await res.json();
    
              state.characters = results;
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          } finally {
            state.isLoading = false;
          }
        },
      },
    };
    
    export default createStore({
      modules: {
        characters: charactersModule,
      },
    });
```

Then in SFC:

```
// some component
```

```js
    ...
      methods: {
        ...mapActions(['getCharacters']),
        }
    
      computed: {
        ...mapState(['characters'])
      },
    
      mounted() {
        this.getCharacters()
      },
```

I expect that inside this SFC I can access computed properties: *characters, isLoading, totalPapges, currentPage and itemsPerPage*. What I actually get from ...mapState(['characters']) is an object with all this props, but I need to get them as single computed props (not as part of an object). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `createNamespacedHelpers`  help to get your state with prefixing them by the module name:

```js
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'

const { mapState, mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('characters')

 ...
      methods: {
        ...mapActions(['getCharacters']),
        }
    
      computed: {
        ...mapState(['characters'])
      },
    
      mounted() {
        this.getCharacters()
      },
```